# Python read Regex from .txt into list and use it to search

Tags: python, regex, list, variables

I am working on a program that reads a number from a .txt file and uses regex to search for it, so if I put 20.00 in the .txt file I want to use regex to look for 20.00 in my scraped list.

The problem is when I read in the regex from the .txt file into a list I do not know how to get regex to read it.

The .txt has something like

NAME = bob

PAYMENT = 20.00

```
payline = control_txt.readline().split(' ')
control_txt.readline()

payAmount = payline[2]
```

I have the extra readline b/c my txt file has lines separated by an enter

```
name = my_lst[0]    

regAmount = re.compile(payAmount)

amount = list(filter(regAmount.match, msg_lst))

if amount:

  print(name + ' ' + '$' + amount[0])
```

I want the final output to look like bob $20.00

It works if I use something like ('20.00') but I need it to be a variable not a hard coded number.

When I try doing

```
payAmount = ("'" + payline[2] + "'")
```

it prints as

```
'20.00
'
```

Comment: ``payAmount = ("'" + payline[2].strip() + "'")`` what you seeing is new line character.

Comment: Please, don't add your solution in the question. Use the answer part if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing trailing newline by changing `payline = control_txt.readline().split(' ')` to `payline = control_txt.readline().strip().split(' ')`. It should work.